Controlling block of displayed page number in pagination
I am using java servlet & oracle 11g
I am working on pagination and code is approximately done but the problem is to control displaying page numbers:
;
Here is my code:
            PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
            ResultSet rs2 = null;
            ps1 = con.prepareStatement("select count(*) from country");
            rs2 = ps1.executeQuery();
            if(rs2.next()) {
            totalNumberOfRecords = rs2.getInt(1);
            }
            rs2.close();
            numberOfPages = totalNumberOfRecords / recordPerPage;

            if (totalNumberOfRecords > numberOfPages * recordPerPage) {
                numberOfPages = numberOfPages + 1;
            }

            // display hyperlinks for each page to view the records
            for (int k = 1; k <= numberOfPages; k++) {
                pw.println("<b><a href=ps?pageno=" + k + ">" + k + "</a></b>");
                pw.println("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            }
        

This code is printing all pages whereas I am trying to print just 5 pages like: 1 2 3 4 5 and when click 6th record then it show 6 7 8 9 10
Please help me
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/v8Sn5xo7.png
